# Android Intent vs. Message Efficiency?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

I have an app where I am sometimes sending data from an external Service to the app once per second.  The data is an array of about 10 Parselable objects with a few short String and Integer fields.

There are two ways I have tried sending the data from the external service:

1. With a Message delivering to a singleton class in the application:

   `Message msg = Message.obtain();`

   `msg.obj = data;`
   `messenger.send(msg);`
2. With an Intent delivering to an `IntentService` in the app:

   `intent.putExtra(dataName, data);`

   `context.startService(intent);`

Both work, but I prefer the Intent approach because it potentially allows me to bootstrap my app if it isn't running when the `Service` sends it data.

Is there anything wrong with this approach given the relatively high rate of data transfers?

Is an `Intent` any less efficient than a `Message`?

Comment: if you have a lot of data to share, a contentprovider may be more appropriate

Comment: it looks like ContentProvider requires Apps to pull data.  In my case, I need to push data to the App, because the data are arriving intermittently from external sensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put very big data into your Intent it can freeze the application. Other than that I don't know. Actually, if what you've done works for you then it's fine as long as it works.